# Python selenium: wait until element is clickable - not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, click

I will test a web-app. there is a button available in my table to select all entries.
I've tried:

```
driver.wait.until(ExpectedCondition.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "myXpath"))).click()
```

selenium clicks on the button, but nothing happens. (also with send_Keys(Keys.Return)) the application is developed with GXT, I thing that there is much javascript behind the button. Is there is possibility to wait until a eventloader is ready? waiting before a click solves the problem, but not a solution for automated testing.

Comment: you'll need to share the code or url to get thorough assistance.  can you do that?

Answer (score 113):

The correct syntax for an explicit wait in Python using a Selenium driver is:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myElement")))
```

Better that After above you do :
**element.click();**

**So in your case :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "myXpath")))

element.click();
```

Better you follow it. Also, share your whole code so that I may correct it. Just 1 line of code is a little confusing to understand.

Comment: can you imagine that `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "myXpath"))).click()` gives the same error for me? btw, did you notice the semicolon?

Comment: Not work for me too - -

Comment: Not for me either :)

Comment: What if we don't have the element xpath but we have the element itself?

Answer (score 6):

I had also that problem... Web apps have views over views and Appium sometimes gets wrong.

This worked for me:

```
x = webElement.location['x'] + (webElement.size['width']/2)
y = webElement.location['y'] + (webElement.size['height']/2)
print("x: "+x+" - y: "+y)

//I have setted a 200 milli duration for the click...
//I use tap just for Android... If is iOS for me it works better touchAction
driver.tap([(x,y)], 200)
```

**Edit**:

I misunderstood your question... Sorry...
Maybe modifying your Xpath to:
(don't know if this will work at a web app)

```
xpath = "//whatever_goes_here[@clickable='true']"
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it is probably too late, but for me the solution was to add this line before all the elements clicks:

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.scrollBehavior = "auto"')
```

Nowadays, sites tend to have a `scrholl-behavior` set to `auto`. Drivers do not know that, though they do know when an element is outside the view. So, what happens is a driver tries to click the element. The driver sees that the element is outside the view, so it calls a scroll method and after that immediately clicks the element without waiting for scrolling to  finish. And the scrolling does take some time because of its behavior set to `auto`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait=WebDriverWait(driver,5)
a= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(('id or xpath or class or any thing else ','enabled_trigger')))
a.click()
```

please note you must have two parentheses in element.to_be_clickable(())