# Trouble clicking a three way toggle switch using selenium webdriver with Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to click a three way toggle using selenium with python.The html element Ids are dynamic. So I have tried with an XPath where class contains a specific text! But I seeing 'element not found'/'element not visible' whole day!

I've tried with below line of code but no help.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'switch switch-three toggle ios') and contains(text(),'Available')]").click()
```

Here is the HTML code of the page and I want to click on - 'Available'

```
<label class="switch switch-three toggle ios" id="radio8526" onclick="" style="float: left; width: 300px; height:15px; margin-right: 20px;margin-left: 20px;">          
    <input id="available8526" value="available" onclick="setVersioningIdFun('8526');document.getElementById('toggleStateButton').click();;" name="onoffswitch8526" type="radio">                    
        <label for="available8526" onclick="">Available</label>
    <input id="unavailable8526" value="unavailable" onclick="setVersioningIdFun('8526');document.getElementById('toggleStateButton').click();;" name="onoffswitch8526" type="radio">
        <label for="unavailable8526" onclick="">Unavailable</label>
    <input id="archived8526" value="archived" onclick="setVersioningIdFun('8526');document.getElementById('toggleStateButton').click();;" name="onoffswitch8526" type="radio" checked="">
        <label for="archived8526" onclick="">Finalised</label>
<a class="slide-button"></a>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

From w3c [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings) You can use this to solve your problem

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[id^="available"]').click()
```

Comment: Tried But confronted with below error again!  selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible

Comment: You can try debugging to see if its finding the element without clicking it, there might be the chance that the element we are trying to click is the not visible and that's why its not clickable.There might be other elements like <label> or <a> that will receive the click.

Comment: I think label is the element that is clickable , can you please try this and confirm browser.find_element_by_css_selector('label[for^="available"]').click()

Comment: Tried but no help.

Comment: If nothing works then your last stop would be javascript executor . You can use the onclick values [onclick="setVersioningIdFun('8526');document.getElementById('toggleStateButton').click();] and execute them with the help of javascript executor.

Comment: The problem is - this Id here '8526', it will be dynamically changing. So I need a more generalized solution here..

Comment: Then you can fetch that part using above code, above code is only throwing exception on clicking so instead of using .click just get the id="radio8526" attribute and then get id using substring. And then will be able to use js executor.

Comment: Tried, this time no error has been thrown, rather the webpage is loaded and nothing happened. Tried with below code -      browser.execute_script("setVersioningIdFun('8526');document.getElementById('toggleStateButton').click();;") . Point to be noted here, same JS executer is defined for toggle state 'available/unavailable'.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of button and its html. Does html contains any custom-tags ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `value` attribute, e.g.

```
input[value='available']
```

You might need to add a wait for clickable to make sure the page has loaded. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110008/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-clickable-not-working) for more info and some examples.