# Selenium Click JS Button - Python?

Tags: python, selenium, button, click, refresh

yeah, there are similar question, but upon reading through them I weren't able to find a solution for my problem.

Following situation: I'm tryin to click the "reply" button on "https://charleston.craigslist.org/ctd/d/charleston-2018-nissan-sentra-sedan-4d/7108660907.html" and after executing this click a popups shows up where I shall click another button, but let's start with the first button as the "reply" click itself is very trouble-making.

The reply button has the following X-Path:

```
'/html/body/section/section/header/div[2]/div/button'
```

speaking of which the source code is:

```
<button role="button" class="reply-button js-only" data-href="/__SERVICE_ID__/chs/ctd/7108660907">
      reply
    </button>
```

(see code on mentioned website).

However, my approach with Selenium (Python) doesn't work:

```
reply_button = '/html/body/section/section/header/div[2]/div/button'
driver.get('https://charleston.craigslist.org/ctd/d/charleston-2018-nissan-sentra-sedan-4d/7108660907.html')

driver.find_element_by_xpath(reply_button).click()
```

Everytime I tried, the website just loads up properly (even with implementing time.sleep(x)) and tries to click the button, but this fails and the website just refreshes - my guess is that they either regocnize the browser being Selenium-controlled, that the click isn't legitimate or that I didn't catch anything right in my code.. Anyone able to help out?

Btw I already tried searching "by_class_name", that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Xpath: `'/html/body/section/section/header/div[2]/div/button'` is like when you get a map with instructions like `step forward until you see a car then turn left 30° then step forward until you see a tree then hop twice then go to the second house to your right`. Not safe to use, avoid such paths. If the page layout changes, your path may become invalid.

Try this:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="reply-button js-only"]')
button.click()
```

Clicking the button opens a "show phone number" popup (which may be located by `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="show-phone"]')`).

Explanation:

If you want proper Xpath, inspect what you want to interact with. The button you want to click is this:

```
<button role="button" class="reply-button js-only" data-href="/__SERVICE_ID__/chs/ctd/7108660907">
      reply
    </button>
```

You can see that it has no "id" tag but it is a button with a specific class. You may copy right away the "class" part -> `class="reply-button js-only"`

Now you can check if is it unique enough:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="reply-button js-only"]')
```

If "find elements" returns a single result, usually you should be OK. You can see that all I did is that I pasted the class inside this: `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@` and this `]')`.

If you need more accuracy, you can specify that it is a button:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="reply-button js-only"]')
```

Or it is the direct child of the element with class: `class="actions-combo"`, so a more safe path would be:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="actions-combo"]/button[@class="reply-button js-only"]')
```

This pattern works for all webelement attributes, not just for classes. You could use the `role="button"` too for more filtering. Look up for Xpath, it is a pretty neat stuff.

Comment: How did you get this alternative XPath?

Comment: I'll add to the answer, hold on.

Comment: Thanks for this in-depth explanation. Helped me a lot and was able to properly click on the reply button :) One more question is left (if you don't mind answering): How would you check if "//*[@class="show-phone"]" is available (and then clicking on it to finally unhide the number and/or being able to copy the text)?

Comment: For that, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110008 the proper way doing it is: `EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "myXpath")))`

Comment: That's a genius way to approach this! I've thought of a try/except block, but that doesn't take any waiting time (except you use time.sleep(x)) into account.. Thanks a lot for your help!