# How to use selenium to click on this element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

How can I click on this element using selenium? I was tried using:(but was not successful)

```
divselected = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(div[aria-label="Add a public comment..."])

divselected.click()
```

I also tried

```
divselected = driver.find_element_by_id("contenteditable-root")
divselected.click()
```

The div I am trying to click:

```
<div id="contenteditable-root" contenteditable="true" dir="auto" class="style-scope yt-formatted-string" aria-label="Add a public comment..."></div>'
```

Comment: Have you encountered iframe?

Comment: @Ruyut I am not sure how to check for that.

Comment: then you can show all html or url

Comment: Sometimes you need to trigger more events than just click for it to work.

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 I get an error that the element cannot be found.

Comment: @Ruyut https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYSOKz3Bfg8

Comment: @Ruyut I am trying to click on the textbox where you write your comment.

Comment: Before clicking the element, can you add a wait for element to be clickable : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28110129/7964299 ?
And also you can use xpath like `//div[contains(@aria-label, 'Add a public comment')]`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help:

```
divselected=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Add a public comment')]")
```

Comment: I get the following:

 driver.find_element_by_xpath(//*[contains(text(),'Add a public comment')])
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Updated  code ..forgot to put double quotes.it should work now and it will return one matching element.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
divselected = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Add a public comment...')]")

divselected[0].click()
```

Comment: How to add comment after this click. I tried sendKeys does not work.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```js
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'contenteditable-root').click()
```

or instead of ID use Class Name.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).