# Expected Conditions Wait until Visible Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to click an element using selenium as shown below -

```py
def colour(self):
    self.driver.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable('//*[@id="add-remove-buttons"]/input')
```

I need the driver to wait until the element is visible, how do I go about doing that.

Comment: You need to use a WebDriverWait as illustrated [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: This answer seems to answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28110129/5911972

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
element= WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 'YOURXPATH')))
```

List of  functions available

1. presence_of_element_located
2. visibility_of_element_located
3. presence_of_all_elements_located
4. text_to_be_present_in_element
   and many more