# How can I find and click data-qa button with a Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

trying to find a button that contains **data-qa** attribute. Try to handle it with following scheme:

```
x = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("button[data-qa='deal-button']")
x[0].click()
```

As result getting an error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If I trying something like this:

```
button = (By.XPATH, "//button[@data-qa='deal-button']")
button.click()
```

There is another issue:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'click'
```

What shall I do, to click on this button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IndexError: list index out of range` probably means that `x` is an empty array. You can conditionally try clicking the button only if the button is present with something like this

```
if len(x) > 0:
    x[0].click()
```

What is probable is that you need to add a wait before the click because the element is not rendered yet. For further information I suggest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110008/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-clickable-not-working) thread.

Comment: Thanks Mate!
With a delay, code start working.