# How do I get selenium to wait until multiple elements are clickable and then return them as something with a length?

Tags: python, selenium

I have code that works shown below; however I would like to speed it up by removing my sleep command and replacing it with something like:

```
element =WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"myElement")))
```

from [Python selenium: wait until element is clickable - not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110008/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-clickable-not-working)

However, redoing *time_element* or *review_element* in this format gives the error: TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()

Is there an equivalent function that will let me wait for multiple elements and then let my code progress as normal?

```
while(True):
    
    #finds the time element by searching all elements tagged with time
    
    #finds the review element by searching all images and taking their
    #description, this is then filtered to remove image tags not from reviews
    
    try:
        
        time_element=driver.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME, value="time")
        review_element=driver.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME, value="img")

        for ii in range(len(time_element)):
            time_list.append(time_element[ii].text)
    
        for iii in range(len(review_element)):
            review_list.append(review_element[iii].get_attribute('alt'))
        
        NEXT=driver.find_element(By.NAME, value='pagination-button-next')
        actions=ActionChains(driver)
        actions.click(NEXT)
        actions.perform()
    
        time.sleep(2)
        
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
```

Comment: "driver.implicitly_wait(TIME IN SECONDS)" should do the trick :)

Comment: Thanks Lobstergoat, but I'm looking for a function that I don't have to put in an arbitrary time myself.